# Program runs only under Valgrind, aborts otherwise

Tags: fortran, valgrind

I have a program which crashes if executed in shell with a simple "aborted". This usually points to some memory issues, so i ran the program under valgrind. The strange thing is that now it runs and gives the expected output. I used the exactly same build for both tests. Here's the Valgrind output:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./datar_test
==1203== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1203== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1203== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1203== Command: ./datar_test
==1203== 
==1203== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1203==    at 0x60382D: __intel_sse2_strcpy (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x57EE17: for__add_to_lf_table (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x5BC0E8: for__open_proc (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x585DAF: for__open_default (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x5A97C3: for_write_seq_lis (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x40E302: fruit_mp_init_fruit_ (fruit.f90:635)
==1203==    by 0x44B58B: MAIN__ (datar_test.f90:18)
==1203==    by 0x4032DD: main (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1203==    at 0x4C29110: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1203==    by 0x59221C: for__get_vm (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x5BA84D: for__open_proc (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x585DAF: for__open_default (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x5A97C3: for_write_seq_lis (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203==    by 0x40E302: fruit_mp_init_fruit_ (fruit.f90:635)
==1203==    by 0x44B58B: MAIN__ (datar_test.f90:18)
==1203==    by 0x4032DD: main (in /home/SERVER-hoffmann/sync/04_DATAR/datar_shared/Unittest/datar_test)
==1203== 

 Test module initialized

    . : successful assert,   F : failed assert 

 --------------
 Starting contact force spectrum test
==1203== Syscall param sched_setaffinity(mask) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==1203==    at 0x6B6EFB9: syscall (in /lib64/libc-2.19.so)
==1203==    by 0x40A0787: __kmp_affinity_determine_capable (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x4089F97: __kmp_env_initialize(char const*) (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x4081175: ??? (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x4074428: __kmp_get_global_thread_id_reg (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x407FF98: __kmp_parallel_initialize (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x406EC7D: omp_get_num_procs (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libiomp5.so)
==1203==    by 0x54211FA: MKL_get_N_Cores (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
==1203==    by 0x5420CA8: mkl_read_threads_env (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
==1203==    by 0x5420694: mkl_serv_mkl_domain_get_max_threads (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
==1203==    by 0x57BB632: mkl_dft_commit_descriptor_d_c2c_1d_omp (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_thread.so)
==1203==    by 0x4F4279C: mkl_dft_dfti_commit_descriptor_external (in /global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_lp64.so)
==1203==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==1203== 
OMP: Warning #2: Cannot open message catalog "libiomp5.cat":
OMP: System error #2: No such file or directory
OMP: Hint: Check NLSPATH environment variable, its value is "/global/linux/64_bit/opt/intel/mkl/10.2.2.025/lib/em64t/locale/%l_%t/%N".
OMP: Info #3: Default messages will be used.
==2910== 
==2910== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2910==     in use at exit: 2,594 bytes in 8 blocks
==2910==   total heap usage: 2,462 allocs, 2,454 frees, 7,276,535 bytes allocated
==2910== 
==2910== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2910==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2910==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2910==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2910==    still reachable: 2,594 bytes in 8 blocks
==2910==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2910== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2910== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==2910== 
==2910== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2910== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Note that i'm compiling with MKL. It can be found that Valgrind gives false positives with MKL (everything that points to mkl libraries).
I'm struggling now to understand why it runs under Valgrind and not without it. Can you explain this to me?

**Edit**: I got rid of some messages, i updated the Valgrind output.

**Update**: Here's an example, where it also doesnt run under Valgrind. It comes down to some Memory Leak i think, but i can't solve it.
Code:

```
module math
    real, parameter :: pi = 4*atan(1.0)
contains
    function fft(x, DirectionKey)
        use MKL_DFTI
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        complex, dimension(:) :: x
        complex, dimension(size(x)) :: fft
        type(DFTI_DESCRIPTOR), pointer :: DFTI
        integer :: DirectionKey, Status

        ! Executing part
        fft = 0
        Status = DftiCreateDescriptor(DFTI,DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_COMPLEX, 1, size(x) )
        Status = DftiCommitDescriptor(DFTI)
        select case (DirectionKey)
            case (1)
                Status = DftiComputeForward(DFTI,x)
                fft = x/size(x)
            case (-1)
                Status = DftiComputeBackward(DFTI,x)
                fft = x
        end select
        Status = DftiFreeDescriptor(DFTI)
    end function fft
    ! ============================================================================
    subroutine NonlinearContactForcePoint(RelativeDisplacementPoint, NormalForcePoint, FricCoeff, Stiffness, ContactForceOUT, ContactForceJacobianOUT)
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: RelativeDisplacementPoint
        real, dimension(size(RelativeDisplacementPoint)), intent(in) :: NormalForcePoint
        real, intent(in) :: FricCoeff, Stiffness

        real, dimension(size(RelativeDisplacementPoint)) :: ContactForce
        real, dimension(size(RelativeDisplacementPoint),2) :: ContactForcePrime
        integer, dimension(size(RelativeDisplacementPoint)) :: ContactStatus
        real, dimension(2), intent(out) :: ContactForceOUT
        real, dimension(2,2), intent(out) :: ContactForceJacobianOUT

        ! Executing part
        call ContactModel(RelativeDisplacementPoint, NormalForcePoint, FricCoeff, Stiffness, ContactForce, ContactStatus)
        call ContactModelPrime(ContactStatus, Stiffness, ContactForcePrime)
        call TimeToFourier(ContactForce, ContactForcePrime, 1, ContactForceOUT, ContactForceJacobianOUT)
    end subroutine NonlinearContactForcePoint
    ! ============================================================================
    subroutine ContactModel(Displacement, NormalForce, FrictionCoefficient, TangentialStiffness, ContactForce, ContactStatus)
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: Displacement
        real, dimension(size(Displacement)), intent(in) :: NormalForce

        real, dimension(size(Displacement)) :: DisplacementSlider
        real :: FrictionCoefficient, TangentialStiffness

        real, dimension(size(Displacement)), intent(out) :: ContactForce
        integer, dimension(size(Displacement)), intent(out) :: ContactStatus
        integer :: ii

        ! Executing part
        ContactForce = 0.0
        ContactStatus = 0
        DisplacementSlider = 0.0

        do ii = 2,size(Displacement)
            if (NormalForce(ii)==0) then
                ContactForce(ii) = 0.0
                DisplacementSlider(ii) = Displacement(ii)
                ContactStatus(ii) = -1
            else
                ! Slip in positive direction
                if (TangentialStiffness*(Displacement(ii) - DisplacementSlider(ii-1))- FrictionCoefficient*NormalForce(ii) > 0) then
                    ContactForce(ii) = -FrictionCoefficient*NormalForce(ii);
                    DisplacementSlider(ii) = Displacement(ii) + ContactForce(ii)/TangentialStiffness;
                    ContactStatus(ii) = 1
                ! Slip in negative direction
                elseif (-TangentialStiffness*(Displacement(ii) - DisplacementSlider(ii-1))- FrictionCoefficient*NormalForce(ii) > 0) then
                    ContactForce(ii) = FrictionCoefficient*NormalForce(ii);
                    DisplacementSlider(ii) = Displacement(ii) + ContactForce(ii)/TangentialStiffness;
                    ContactStatus(ii) = 1
                ! General stick
                elseif (TangentialStiffness*(Displacement(ii) - DisplacementSlider(ii-1))- FrictionCoefficient*NormalForce(ii) <= 0) then
                    ContactForce(ii) = -TangentialStiffness*(Displacement(ii) - DisplacementSlider(ii-1));
                    DisplacementSlider(ii) = DisplacementSlider(ii-1);
                    ContactStatus(ii) = 0
                end if
            end if
        end do
    end subroutine ContactModel
     ! ============================================================================
    subroutine TimeToFourier(TimeSeries, TimeSeriesPrime, Harmonics, RealCoefficients, RealJacobianCoefficients)
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: TimeSeries
        real, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: TimeSeriesPrime
        integer, intent(in) :: Harmonics
        integer :: N
        complex, dimension(1) :: Spectrum, SpectrumPrimeR, SpectrumPrimeI
        real, dimension(2), intent(out) :: RealCoefficients
        real, dimension(2,2), intent(out) :: RealJacobianCoefficients

        ! Executing part
        N = size(TimeSeries)
        Spectrum = CreateSpectrum(TimeSeries(N/2+1:N), Harmonics)
        SpectrumPrimeR = CreateSpectrum(TimeSeriesPrime(N/2+1:N,1), Harmonics)
        SpectrumPrimeI = CreateSpectrum(TimeSeriesPrime(N/2+1:N,2), Harmonics)

        RealCoefficients = [real(Spectrum), -aimag(Spectrum)]
        RealJacobianCoefficients = reshape([real(SpectrumPrimeR), -aimag(SpectrumPrimeR), real(SpectrumPrimeI), -aimag(SpectrumPrimeI)],[2,2])
    end subroutine TimeToFourier
    ! ============================================================================
    subroutine ContactModelPrime(ContactStatus, TangentialStiffness, Prime)
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        integer, dimension(:), intent(in) :: ContactStatus
        real, dimension(size(ContactStatus)) :: dfdrQ, dfdiQ
        real :: TangentialStiffness
        real, dimension(size(ContactStatus),2) :: Prime
        real :: dfdrQ_OLD, dfdiQ_OLD
        integer :: ii

        ! Executing part
        dfdrQ = 0.0
        dfdiQ = 0.0
        dfdrQ_OLD = 0.0
        dfdiQ_OLD = 0.0
        Prime = 0.0
        do ii = 2,size(ContactStatus)
            ! Stick
            if (ContactStatus(ii) == 0) then
                dfdrQ(ii) = -TangentialStiffness*(cos(2*2*pi/size(ContactStatus)*(ii-1))-cos(2*2*pi/size(ContactStatus)*(ii-2))) + dfdrQ_OLD;
                dfdiQ(ii) = -TangentialStiffness*(sin(2*2*pi/size(ContactStatus)*(ii-1))-sin(2*2*pi/size(ContactStatus)*(ii-2))) + dfdiQ_OLD;
            end if
            dfdrQ_OLD = dfdrQ(ii)
            dfdiQ_OLD = dfdiQ(ii)
        end do
        Prime = reshape([dfdrQ, dfdiQ],[size(ContactStatus),2])
    end subroutine ContactModelPrime
        ! ============================================================================
    function CreateSpectrum(TimeSignal, Harmonics)
        implicit none
        ! Declaring part
        real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: TimeSignal
        complex, dimension(size(TimeSignal)) :: Spectrum
        integer, intent(in) :: Harmonics
        complex, dimension(:), allocatable :: CreateSpectrum
        integer :: ii
        ! Executing part
        Spectrum = fft(cmplx(TimeSignal),1)
        if (Harmonics == 0) then
            allocate(CreateSpectrum(1))
            CreateSpectrum = Spectrum(1)
        else
            allocate(CreateSpectrum(Harmonics))
            do ii=1,Harmonics
                CreateSpectrum = 2*Spectrum(Harmonics+1)
            end do
        end if
    end function
end module math

    ! ============================================================================
program test
    use MKL_RCI
    use MKL_RCI_type
    use math
    implicit none
    real, dimension(12,12) :: ContactForceJacobian
    real, dimension(12) :: Displacement
    external :: NonlinearContactForce

    Displacement = [1.0e-5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    if (djacobi(NonlinearContactForce,12,12,ContactForceJacobian,Displacement,1e-8) /= TR_SUCCESS) then
        write(*,*), '| error in djacobi'
        call MKL_FREE_BUFFERS
        stop 1;
    end if
end program test
    ! ============================================================================
subroutine NonlinearContactForce(m,n,RelativeDisplacement, ContactForce, ContactForceJacobian)
    use math
    implicit none
    ! Declaring part
    integer :: m, n
    real, dimension(12) :: RelativeDisplacement
    real, dimension(6) :: RelativeDisplacementPoint
    real, dimension(2) :: ContactForceXi
    real, dimension(2,2) :: ContactForceJacobianXi
    ! Time domain variables
    real, dimension(32) :: NormalForce
    complex, dimension(32) :: RelativeDisplacementPointSpectrum
    real, dimension(32) :: RelativeDisplacementPointTime
    real, dimension(2) :: ContactForceLocal
    real, dimension(2,2) :: ContactForceJacobianLocal
    ! Output variables
    real, dimension(12), intent(out) :: ContactForce
    real, dimension(12,12), intent(out) :: ContactForceJacobian

    ! Executing part
    ContactForce(1:12) = 0
    ContactForceJacobian(1:12,1:12) = 0
    RelativeDisplacementPointTime = 0
    NormalForce = 1
    RelativeDisplacementPointSpectrum = 0
    RelativeDisplacementPointSpectrum(3) = cmplx(RelativeDisplacement(1)/2.0,-RelativeDisplacement(2)/2.0)
    RelativeDisplacementPointSpectrum(32-1) = cmplx(RelativeDisplacement(1)/2.0,RelativeDisplacement(2)/2.0)
    RelativeDisplacementPointTime = real(fft(RelativeDisplacementPointSpectrum,-1))
    call NonlinearContactForcePoint(RelativeDisplacementPointTime, NormalForce,1.0, 1e6, ContactForceLocal, ContactForceJacobianLocal)
    ContactForce(1:2) = ContactForceLocal
    ContactForceJacobian(1:2,1:2) = ContactForceJacobianLocal

end subroutine NonlinearContactForce
```

Compile command (ifort 17.0.1):

```
ifort -g -O0 -CB -CA -CU -fstack-protector -fp-stack-check -traceback -real-size 64 -mkl -I${MKL_ROOT}/include test.f90
```

MKL version: 2017

Comment: You must show your code. Very likely it is buggy. See  [mcve] and [ask]. If it happens for any code, prepare the simplest code possible that still cases the error. Even if it is just a one line, show it. Show us: **1. the exact code, 2. the exact command for compilation, 3. your compiler and library versions.**

Comment: *I used the exactly same build for both tests*  But not the same execution environment.  Shoogling the layout of data in memory (and Valgrind makes all sorts of modifications to the environment in which the program runs) might make a jump depending on an uninitialised variable turn from a jump out of the process's address space to one inside its address space.  Or something else entirely ...

Comment: i updated the original post with the requested informations

Comment: Your abort is almost certainly caused by the "Syscall param sched_setaffinity(mask) points to unaddressable byte(s)" error. Don't get hung up on it working in valgrind; valgrind can handle tons of errors because of how it's wrappering memory accesses.